# When inserting data and a picture from Access to Excel automation fails second time code runs

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am working a small office ms-access tool. One of the reports exports data into an Excel template.  that has been working fine.  I decided I needed to add a picture into a second of the workbook's worksheets. The code below works once but when I close the excel application and try a second time I get "1004: Method 'Worksheets' of object '_Application' failed.  I did attempt to correct using the MS help article 178510 which explains the importance of each call to an Excel object, method, or property be qualified with the appropriate object variable. Below is my code. I am new to this and could appreciate any help.

```
Private Sub btnOpReport2_Click()

On Error GoTo Error

Dim myPict As Excel.Picture
Dim rst
Dim XL As Excel.Application
Dim xlWS As Excel.Worksheet
Dim vFile

Set XL = CreateObject("excel.application")

vFile = TempVars("BackPath") & "\Templates\" & "Operation.xltx"

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.OpenQuery ("qry_Ops_to_OAIs")
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tbl_TEMP_OPS_to_OAIs")

With XL
   .Visible = True
   .Workbooks.Open vFile
   .Sheets("Data").Select
   .Range("A2").Select
   .ActiveCell.CopyFromRecordset rst
   .ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Visible = xlSheetHidden


    Set xlWS = Excel.Application.Worksheets("Operation")

    xlWS.Activate

        With xlWS.Range("N8")
            Set myPict = .Parent.Pictures.Insert(TempVars("BackPath") & "\Activity_Documents\" & Me.GraphicLink)
            myPict.Top = .Top
            myPict.Left = .Left
            myPict.Height = 470
            myPict.Width = 500
            myPict.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
        End With

End With


Set rst = Nothing
Set XL = Nothing
Set vFile = Nothing
Set myPict = Nothing
Set xlWS = Nothing
  
DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "tbl_TEMP_OPS_to_OAIs"
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

ExitError:
    Exit Sub
    
Error:
    MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    Resume ExitError
End Sub
```

Comment: Not too bad for a newbie, but to set the worksheet you use the wrong properties as [Excel.Application.Worksheets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.worksheets) is implicit `Excel.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` Also error indicates that the method `Worksheets`of `Application`has failed. Maybe `ActiveWorkbook` isn't the one containing `.Worksheets("Operation")` Store the reference to workbook on `.Open` method, that returns the ref, just need to store it!

Comment: Thanks.  Do you have a preferred reference for learning VBA for Access so i can get a little better at this?

Answer (score 1):

You've attached `.Sheets("Data").Select` to the `Application` object via your `With` block: it would be better to get an explicit reference to the opened workbook and use that instead.

Try this - if it still has issues then comment out the `On Error` and see which line has the problem

```vb
Private Sub btnOpReport2_Click()

    On Error GoTo haveError    ' "Error" as a line label is a bit confusing maybe...
    
    Dim myPict As Excel.Picture
    Dim rst
    Dim XL As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWb As Excel.Workbook   '<<<<<
    Dim vFile
    
    Set XL = CreateObject("excel.application")
    
    vFile = TempVars("BackPath") & "\Templates\" & "Operation.xltx"
    
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.OpenQuery ("qry_Ops_to_OAIs")
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tbl_TEMP_OPS_to_OAIs")

    XL.Visible = True
    Set xlWb = XL.Workbooks.Open(vFile) '<< get a reference to the opened file
   
    With xlWb.Worksheets("Data")
        .Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst
        .Visible = xlSheetHidden
    End With
    
    With xlWb.Worksheets("Operation").Range("N8")
        Set myPict = .Parent.Pictures.Insert(TempVars("BackPath") & _
                                "\Activity_Documents\" & Me.GraphicLink)
        myPict.Top = .Top
        myPict.Left = .Left
        myPict.Height = 470
        myPict.Width = 500
        myPict.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
    End With

    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "tbl_TEMP_OPS_to_OAIs"
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    
ExitError:
        Exit Sub
        
haveError:
        MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
        Resume ExitError

End Sub
```

Comment: *Try this* is usually not considered an answer here. It would be a better answer if you explained the differences in your code and why those differences are a solution to the problem.

Comment: This worked perfectly @Tim Williams!!!!  Thank you!!